# Setting java.time.LocalDate as parameter in myBatis query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, mybatis

I have a simple REST service that take a date as pathvariable and executes a query. I am using `java.time.LocalDate` class to store the date and passing the parameter as below:

```
    <select id="getRecordsUpdatedAfterDate" parameterType="java.time.LocalDate" resultType="String">
        SELECT ID FROM table WHERE REC_UPDT_DT > #{recUpdtDt, jdbcType=DATE}
    </select>
```

But I am not getting any response back from the service. In the logs I have this:

```
2020-04-06 10:16:16.187 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.t.g.a.m.P.getRecordsUpdatedAfterDate: ==>  Preparing: SELECT ID FROM table WHERE REC_UPDT_DT > ?
2020-04-06 10:16:16.188 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.t.g.a.m.P.getRecordsUpdatedAfterDate: ==> Parameters: 2020-01-01(LocalDate)
```

But nothing after this and there is no response either.

Anything I am doing wrong? I am using mybatis 3.5.2, and Spring Boot.

Comment: It seems that some of the target rows are locked. Can you provide a small project that reproduces the issue? Here are [project templates](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) to start with.

Comment: I was impatient more than anything else, the query was taking too long to execute and once I decreased the amount of data that the query was returning, I started getting a response.

Answer (score 0):

if you execute the same query in the datasource you get a single string object ? 
Maybe is because the dataType oor because you get more than one result.

Add your table definition to check ID Type.

Comment: Getting more than one result is not an issue. It just returns a list of String object if there are more than one rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
```